# When using wall clock time, is the timestamp passed to a punctuator milliseconds since UNIX epoch? (Kafka)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I'm using wall clock time and want to compare the timestamp passed to a punctuator's `punctuate` method to a UNIX timestamp stored in a record field.

Will the timestamp passed to the punctuator always represent milliseconds since UNIX epoch? It'd be helpful to know what Java code is being used to get wall clock time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for WALL_CLOCK_TIME punctuation the passed `timestamp` will be the system timestamp, i.e., UNIX epoch ms timestamp, returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()`.